# C# File to Dictionary, but taking pairs of words

Tags: c#, string, linq, dictionary

I am thinking about making a dictionary that contains words pairs as well as single words from a file.

Standard "single word" looks like:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private void GetWords(string[] file)
{ 
   tempDict = file
   .SelectMany(i => File.ReadLines(i)
   .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
   .GroupBy(word => word)                    
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
}
```

And the string:

> Adam likes coffee

will be:

> Adam ; likes ; coffee

But I want to make it so it matches pairs as well (but only the neighbouring ones) so it would look like:

> Adam ; Adam likes ; likes ; likes coffee ; coffee

I am not sure if it is manageable to do, and need some help with this one.

Comment: Are you looking for LINQ solution?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov preferably

Comment: How would you want to group the results?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov dictionary which would be made out of it looked like `{Adam, 1} {Adam likes, 1}` and so on. So grouping by phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MoreLINQ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) has a `Enumerable.Pairwise` which takes the current and the predecessor value and a projections function.

> Returns a sequence resulting from applying a function to each element in the source sequence and its predecessor, with the exception of the first element which is only returned as the predecessor of the second element.

Concatenating that with the original split value array would output:

```
var sentence = "Adam likes coffee";
var splitWords = sentence.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var pairWise = splitWords.Pairwise((first, second) => string.Format("{0} {1}", first,
                                                                               second))
                         .Concat(splitWords)
                         .GroupBy(x => x)
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
```

Would result in:

[image: Output]

Comment: If I am doing more work on words from files for example `.ToLower()` or `.Distinct()` do I need to use it on both of them? Because first one is just a string from what I can tell, and if only in the second one, should it be then after the `.Concat()`?

Comment: After you `Split` the words you can lowercase all the letter before processing with `var lowerCased = sentence.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(string => string.ToLower());`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Why use the non-standard `Pairwise` when `Zip` would do just fine?